# JQuery chosen did not show search box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I have a form with few fields that should use drop down chosen. I have created a class on each select tag. This class is used to apply chosen on each element. I'm not getting any errors once a form is loaded but chosen doesn't work. Only what is displayed on the screen is this:

Chosen Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQEK5.png

Here is my code:

```
<form name="frmDemo" id="frmDemo" method="POST" action="#" class="frmLayout">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Demographic</legend>
        <div class="formItem">
            <label for="city" class="required">City:</label>
            <select name="city" id="city" class="chosen">
                <option value="">Choose City</option>
                <cfoutput query="getCity">
                    <option value="#cityNum#">#cityName#</option>
                </cfoutput>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="formItem">
            <p align="center"><input type="button" name="chSubmit" id="chSubmit" value="Submit"></p>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.chosen').each(function(){
        $(this).chosen();
    });
});
```

Comment: Nothing at all in the javascript console?

Comment: @mkaatman No, everything is loaded js and css. I have used chosen before and never experienced something similar.

Comment: maybe it's your CSS... hiding the input somehow

Comment: Very odd is that chosen will work on the select tag on my main page. Select tag inside of the form has an issue. I'm not sure what could cause this problems. There is few warnings in my console but all of them are related to browser (Mozilla in my case).

Comment: Was this error resolved? @espresso_coffee

Answer (score 1):

Should be your reference not set up properly, use the following:

Load `CSS -> jQuery -> chosen`

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.chosen').each(function() {
    $(this).chosen();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="frmDemo" id="frmDemo" method="POST" action="#" class="frmLayout">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Demographic</legend>
    <div class="formItem">
      <label for="city" class="required">City:</label>
      <select name="city" id="city" class="chosen">
        <option value="">Choose City</option>
        <cfoutput query="getCity">
          <option value="#cityNum#">#cityName#</option>
        </cfoutput>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="formItem">
      <p align="center">
        <input type="button" name="chSubmit" id="chSubmit" value="Submit">
      </p>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```